# Databind to List<> with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a thin dal which exposes CRUD operations using Entity Framework (.net 4.0)

Can I have a List that gets updated automatically to reflect updates in my model? It is a single user (service) application.

```
List<Advertisement> list = dal.GetActiveAdvertisements();
```

`list.Count` is 5

```
dal.InsertActiveAdvertisements(newAdvertisement);
```

`list.Count` is still 5 but i would like to have 6 entries.

Can I accomplish this?

Thanks Jørgen

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking to do is easy, but probably not good practice:

```
public class DAL {

    private List<Advertisement> _activeAdvertisements;
    public List<Advertisement> GetActiveAdvertisements() 
    {
        return _activeAdvertisements ?? _activeAdvertisements = // ... data access;
    }
    public void InsertActiveAdvertisements(Advertisement newAdvertisement)
    {
        var adList = GetActiveAdvertisements();
        adList.Add(newAdvertisements);
        // ... Add values to the database
    }
}
```

I wouldn't personally do things this way:

1. It's not thread safe: if two threads try adding an advertisement at the same time, you may have problems.
2. It's easy to get out of sync with the database. What if an advertisement gets added in a different instance of `DAL`?

Comment: `ObservableCollection` would be better in this case

Comment: How *would* you do it, then?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @phoog: It depends on the specific situation, of course, but I'd probably start by returning an `IEnumerable<Advertisement>`, since I don't want consumers changing the list I return. Establish the idea that the returned collection is ephemeral: if someone wants an updated list, they need to ask the DAL service for it every time. Then cache the list in a static MemoryCache and tell the cache to  purge itself whenever someone adds an advertisement. Or use any other caching strategy: the point is that since consumers always go to your class for the updated list you have one point of control.